# Can I apply unit conversion to a gridview column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a column in my gridview which displays the total cost of certain items which is pulled from my database table. However, my users also have a currency information attached to their account. What I would like to do is convert this column based on the individual user's currency info. I have tried the following:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="currencyconvfactor" runat="server" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="Total">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# currencyconvfactor.Value %> //this is just a test. see below for the issue.
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            currencyconvfactor.Value = 12345 
            //i simplified retrieving the specific factor value here as I do some database commands to pull the specific value
    }
```

However, I notice that the template field column is always empty. Does that mean that the gridviews are generated before the page load event? If so, how could I perform the column conversions on the first page load? More specifically, how can I access the conversion factor to perform the conversion in time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After defining the values​​, call GridView.DataBind()

Comment: Wow this was the problem. Such a dumb mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at using a [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event to access the column and do whatever computation you need:

**.aspx:**

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Template Field">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblConvValue" Runat="server" /> 
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Get the current row's data
        DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

        // Do your conversion
        var conv = int.Parse(rowView["valueToConvert"].ToString()); 
        var converted = conv * 12345; // Whatever conversion you want.

        // Set the value of the control in the ItemTemplate
        Label lblConvValue= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblConvValue");
        lblConvValue.Text = converted.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all rows use the same Currency conversion factor, you can do the following. 
 ...

```
 <ItemTemplate>
    <%#GetCurrencyconvfactor()%>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

...

In the code behind define a method to return the value

```
    public string GetCurrencyconvfactor()
    {
        //you can also pass in custID as an argument if each row uses different factor
        return "123"; // or get this from the user profile/settings 
    }
```